# Referencing DOM elements from within a Knockout Component

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, reference, custom-component

I'm writing a knockout component, and I need to do some manipulation of the DOM objects within the component via jquery.

How do I get a reference to an element? I can't put an `id` attribute on it because it'll be repeated for each instance of the component on the page.

Consider this example:

```
<!-- component template -->
<div>
    <p data-bind="text: name">
    <audio></audio>
</div>


// View model
define(["jquery", "knockout"], function ($, ko) {

    var audioElement = $("????");

    function vm(params) {        
        var self = this;
        self.name = params.name;    
    };

    return vm;
});
```

How can I grab a jquery reference to the audio tag, when there will be more than one instance of the component on the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you register your component with a `createViewModel` factory function you have access to the relevant DOM parts upon instantiating a component.

From [the docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html#a-createviewmodel-factory-function), see the comments about `componentInfo`:

```
ko.components.register('my-component', {
  viewModel: {
    createViewModel: function(params, componentInfo) {
      // - 'params' is an object whose key/value pairs are the parameters
      //   passed from the component binding or custom element
      // - 'componentInfo.element' is the element the component is being
      //   injected into. When createViewModel is called, the template has
      //   already been injected into this element, but isn't yet bound.
      // - 'componentInfo.templateNodes' is an array containing any DOM
      //   nodes that have been supplied to the component. See below.

      // Return the desired view model instance, e.g.:
      return new MyViewModel(params);
    }
  },
  template: ...
});
```

I'd strongly suggest to do the DOM manipulation via knockout and its data-binds though.